# Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()' which I am using to initialize Adapter

Tags: java, android, list, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a custom Adapter *MyAdapter* and inflating a ListView *listView* to display an array of String *data*. I am getting error while initializing *MyAdapter* using *getActivity()* method, as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private String[] data = {"Sanskrit", "Bhojpuri", "Newari", "Magar",
            "Gurung", "English", "Maithili", "Tamil", "Hindi",
            "French", "German", "Russian", "Chinese"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    String[] data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int res, String[] data) {
        super(context,res);

        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false);

        TextView textView = row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(data[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share **stacktrace error** info.

Comment: @JeelVankhede There is no stack trace. It's a compile time error.

Comment: Please do not use "Solved" in question body or title. Post a self-answer instead or accept one of the answers which helped you in solving the problem.

Comment: @Shashanth I added the solution at the  Answers. This was my first post. So wasn't aware about it. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 3):

You're already in the Activity when you initialize `MyAdapter`. The Activity class has no `getActivity()` method because it's already the Activity.

Use `this`:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you copied the code from the net.  
You should use `getActivity()` when you work with a fragment to refer to the host activity's context, but since you're in an activity you only need `this` to get the current activity's context.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() method returns the context of the activity.

Try this

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(YourActivityName.this,data);`

If you are wanting the current activity then just

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the context in many ways:

```java
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(),data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or you can use the application context:

```java
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or the current activity context:

```java
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.

```
 MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),data); 
    ...
```

to

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_list_view,data);
```

and

```
public MyAdapter(Context context,int res,String[] data) {
super(context,res);
```

to

```
public MyAdapter(Context context,int resource,String[] data) {
super(context,resource,data);
```

I was passing wrong arguments while initializing the MyAdapter instance and while creating MyAdapter constructor and calling super.

Thanks everyone for your answer. ;)